# Grid members (cells) are too large

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have a Dev express grid - is there anything else i need to code that would control the size of the cells? they are way too large, like 2 inches wide. But I reduce the width here and it makes no Change.

```
 </DataItemTemplate>
            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="PAYSOURCE" VisibleIndex="1" Caption="Paysource" Width="20%">
                <CellStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></CellStyle>
            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="GROUPING" VisibleIndex="2" Caption="Grouping" Width="20%">
                <CellStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></CellStyle>
            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn VisibleIndex="3" FieldName="OTC_NON_COVER" Caption="OTC Non-Cover" Width="10%">
                <PropertiesTextEdit DisplayFormatString="C"></PropertiesTextEdit>
            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn VisibleIndex="4" FieldName="RX_NON_COVER" Caption="Rx Non-Cover" Width="10%">
                <PropertiesTextEdit DisplayFormatString="C"></PropertiesTextEdit>
            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataColumn VisibleIndex="5" FieldName="APPLY_NON_COVERED_RULES" Caption="Apply Non Covered Rule" Width="10%">
                <CellStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></CellStyle>
            </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Comment: If you take out all the width="" from all the columns, won't it auto-size the cells for you, to fit the data bound to them?

Comment: yes but its same. I think the issue is that this grid will grow to 100% so even if you make each 10% it will fill out the remaining 50% space as it sees fit. the question now is how to reduce the overall size of the grid.

Comment: I read on Dev Express that you'll have to resize the container as a whole to make those columns narrower.

Comment: Can't post the link, it is secure link, just google dev express Grid View and you should get the online documentation for it.

Comment: ok gr8 thanks, how can i credit you for the answer please.

Comment: the only issue i see is the column heading, if long this make the entire col as long.

Answer (score 1):

I read on Dev Express that you'll have to resize the container as a whole to make those columns narrower.  Can't post the link, it is secure link, just google dev express Grid View and you should get the online documentation for it.

There should be a way to set the column headings statically in the grid, then you can name them as you please and make them as short as you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GridView.BestFitColumns() method.
[More](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_BestFitColumnstopic)